# Correct owner, group and permissions when mounting an image file

Tags: filesystems, permissions, mount, users

Suppose I have an image `home.img` of a home partition of another linux machine (B). On that machine there is a users `userB` and there is a special group, `groupB`. Consider for example a file `fileB` in the `home` partition of machine B. Suppose it is owned by `userB` and `groupA`.

Now if I mount (via `mount home.img /mnt/homeB -o ro`) the `img` file on another linux machine A (logged in as `userA`), `fileB` is now owned by `userA`.

Is it possible to modify the mount options such that the owner, groups and permissions are shown on machine A, as it would be shown directly on machine B (for example that `fileB` is owned by `userB` and not by `userA`)? Do I have to create a dummy `userB` and `groupB` on machine A?

Comment: See if `bindfs` meet your needs.

Comment: @enzotib bindfs does some translation of permissions, but it doesn't do arbitrary translations of users, which I think student wants. Bindfs only translates one user and one group.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is that `userB` on `machineB` has the same UID number as `userA` on `machineA`.

Linux filesystems store ownership by UID number, not name. So if the file is owned by a user with UID number of `1000`, then whenever that filesystem is mounted on another machine, the file will appear to be owned by whatever user has a UID number of `1000`.
Now in theory a filesystem could store file ownership by user name instead, but I do not think any do.